# Can't get a function that is supposed to return bool to work in python

Tags: python, boolean

I wrote:

```
def is_vowel(letter:str) ->bool:
    """
    takes a one-character-long string and returns 
    True if that character is a vowel and False otherwise.
    """
    if letter in ['a' or 'A' or 'e' or 'E' or 'i' or 'I' or 'o' or 
                  'O' or 'u' or 'U']:
        return True

print(is_vowel('A'))
```

but it prints `None`. Why?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a piece of code in there?

Comment: `or` doesn't work the way you think it does.

Comment: are you trying to set the input and return types with `(letter:str) ->bool`?

Comment: @agconti those are [function annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/), used in Python 3

Comment: The problem in your code is `letter != 'a' or 'A' or 'e' or 'E'`. What you are actually asking python to check is `letter != 'a' or True or True or True`, since non empty strings are always `True`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, if I've answered your question, you can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it, which will add plus 2 to your reputation. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, look at `('a' or 'A')` in an interpreter. It will return `'a'`, so you were originally looking for character in a list with only one character: `['a']`. That is because a string of length greater than zero evaluates to `True` in a boolean context, which the `or` created. `or` will return the first True-ish thing, in this case, `'a'`.

I recommend for readability, use as in the following function, first take the lowercase version of the letter, then tell if it exists in a canonical representation of a string of all such characters, and just return the result of the test for membership. No need for if-then control-flow:

```
def is_vowel(letter: str) -> bool:
    """
    takes a one-character-long string and returns True if 
    that character is a vowel and False otherwise.
    """
    return letter.lower() in 'aeiou'

print(is_vowel( 'b'))
```

In Python 2,

```
def is_vowel(letter):
    """
    takes a one-character-long string and returns True if 
    that character is a vowel and False otherwise.
    """
    return letter.lower() in 'aeiou'
```

The reason you're getting `None` is because your function (a different version simplified below) doesn't return False if it doesn't return True. And when a function doesn't return anything specified, it returns None. So below is a version closer to yours that returns False if it doesn't return True.

```
def is_vowel(letter: str) -> bool:
if letter in ['a', 'A', 'e', 'E', 'i', 'I', 'o', 'O', 'u', 'U']:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

But I think this is better written:

```
def is_vowel(letter: str) -> bool:
    return letter in ['a', 'A', 'e', 'E', 'i', 'I', 'o', 'O', 'u', 'U']
```

Or as I did, above.

Answer (score 3):

Use `in` keyword:

```
if letter in ['a', 'e', 'i', ...]:
```

EDIT: related question: [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)